# Write lists into a text file

Tags: python

I need to save the uniquewords and positions in a text file I tried

```
sentence = raw_input("Enter a sentence: ")
sentence = sentence.lower().split()
uniquewords = []
for word in sentence:
    if word not in uniquewords:
        uniquewords.append(word)

positions = [uniquewords.index(word) for word in sentence]

recreated = " ".join([uniquewords[i] for i in positions])

positions = [x+1 for x in positions]

print uniquewords
print positions
print recreated

file = open('textfile.txt', 'w')
file.write('\n'.join(uniquewords))
file.close()
```

The outcome is fine in python  but the uniquewords wont go into the textfile.
I am using version 2.7.5 and notepad as the textfile.

Comment: you have a comma instead of a period between the string and join.  You want `'\n'.join...` instead of `'\n',join...`

Comment: join is an attribute of a string, tryfile.write('\n'.join(uniquewords)) instead of file.write('\n',join(uniquewords)) (change the come into a dot)

Comment: the program runs but nothing now appears in the text file

Answer (score 2):

`join` is a string method, you should not use a comma but a dot between `'\n'` and `join`.

```
file = open('textfile.txt', 'w')
file.write('\n'.join(uniquewords))
file.close()
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this it runs fine but nothing appears in the text file

Comment: Runs fine for me, can you edit your question and add the corrected complete code ?

Comment: Ok, what text file are you using

Comment: Exactly the same, I copy-pasted your code (with the dot instead of the comma) and it's working perfectly. Have a look at your directory permissions ?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that but is it because im using notepad?

Answer (score 0):

You need to combine the two parts you mentioned in your question. Put the first part at the end, instead of, or as well as your print statements.

```
sentence = raw_input("Enter a sentence: ")
sentence = sentence.lower().split()
uniquewords = []
for word in sentence:
    if word not in uniquewords:
        uniquewords.append(word)

positions = [uniquewords.index(word) for word in sentence]

recreated = " ".join([uniquewords[i] for i in positions])

positions = [x+1 for x in positions]

file = open('textfile.txt', 'w')
file.write('\n'.join(uniquewords))
file.close()
```

As your example stands, it currently tries to write `uniquewords` to the file before it contains anything.

Comment: That's what I have done but nothing appears in the text file still

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: Version 2.7.5 of python

Comment: With your 3 print statements, do you see the output you expect? We need to see your full code to diagnose the problem. Please hit "Edit" on your first question, and add the entire file you are running.

Comment: How are you running it? Try saving the file as testwriting.py and running "python testwriting.py" from the command line?

Comment: I know where I went wrong now thanks, the text file had been created just I couldn't find it thanks :)